# How to access pipeline name in the freestyle job

Tags: jenkins

I have a pipeline which triggers a jenkins freestyle job.
How to access the pipeline name from the freestyle job.
I tried using ${BUILD_CAUSE} but it shows the value as UPSTREAMTRIGGER.

How to get the pipeline name?

Answer (score 0):

`JOB_NAME` may contain the name of the job that you're after, unless it was triggered by an upstream job.

See a list of generic [Jenkins environment variables](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-belowJenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables) that are available in most builds. The best way to find out what environment variables are available is to run `sh 'printenv'` in the steps.

If you need the name of the upstream job in a downstream job, I'd suggest setting a parameter on the downstream job and then referencing it when you trigger the job.

e.g. Upstream Pipeline job:

```
...
  step {
    build job: 'freestyle-downstream-job', parameters: [
      string(name: 'upstream_job_name', value: "${JOB_NAME}")
    ]
  }
...
```

Comment: I guess it should be available by default in cause object. Please suggest how to use the existing one instead of passing as parameter.